# How do I destroy an instantiated game object clone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy, gameobject

I am trying to check if an object appears above a number. And if it does I want to destroy it and recreate it. And if it does not I want to create it. I have tried the following code. It creates the object but does not destroy it.

```cs
GameObject newGameObject = null;
if (x > 3.14)
        {
            if (newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid())
            {
                Destroy(newGameObject);
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
            else
            {
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }

        }
else
        {
             Destroy(newGameObject);
        }
```

When running multiple times the objects never destroy but stack and I can see them in the hierarchy not being destroyed.

I have tried giving the newGameObject a tag so that I could destroy the tagged item and it did not tag any clones.

I tried find name of gameobject + "(clone)" and destroy them but it did not let me.

I have tried adding 1f timer, destroy(newGameObject,1f) does not destroy game object.

Comment: This is part of `Update`? It is weird as you declare object multiple times...

Comment: It is part of onclick, but it could be part of update I assume it could be used in update to check values of an updating source.

Comment: It was a typo that I wrote GameObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is all part of an OnClick callback then here is why you are not destroying any object:

The main culprit is your definition of `GameObject newGameObject = null` inside the method. The value of `newGameObject` will always be null inside of the method so the statement `if (newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid())` will always return false because newGameObject is always null and that is why you see all those GameObjects being instantiated. The case when `if(x > 3.14)` fails does not destroy anything as you are trying to destroy `newGameObject`, which is null.

To be able to destroy the object you will need a class field to store the reference to the last GameObject spawned.

Your MonoBehaviour will then look something like this:

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject newGameObject;

    /* other useful code */

    public void OnClick(){
        if (x > 3.14)
        {
            if (newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid())
            {
                Destroy(newGameObject);
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
            else
            {
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
             Destroy(newGameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Removing GameObject newGameObject = null;
and declaring it as a private fixed it, It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
GameObject newGameObject = null;
if (x > 3.14)
        {
            if (newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid())
            {
                Destroy(newGameObject);
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
            else
            {
                newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }

        }
else
        {
             Destroy(newGameObject);
        }
```

Try this. Everytime when you create a new object after destroy will create one new object.